# View mint date for ERC-721 / ERC-1155 token

Tags: nft, security

I was wondering if it's possible to calculate the initial mint date for a token.

I was thinking perhaps one could check the block-timestamp for the transaction in which a token was first minted?

I was also thinking that this should only be valid for tokens pointing to the IPFS - to prevent someone pretending to mint something in the past - by changing the metadata on their server to relate to a token they hadn't originally minted

Comment: Did you ever find a way ?

Comment: @Stormsson Haven't implemented this yet, but each NFT is minted in a transaction, and each transaction has a time it was processed at - with usually around 15 seconds of accuracy

Comment: I think I'm missing one important piece of info: how do you find the tx by interacting with the smart contract ? I am used to use the ABI somehow, but I wouldn't say there's a way from this approach

Answer (score 1):

Most ERC721 NFTs have a **Transfer log** in the transaction receipts where you can see the initial mint from **0x0** address to target address/contract. You can trace that transaction to its associated blocknumber which will have a timestamp.

I've heard that the miners set the timestamp for mined blocks, but not sure if that's true. Might be best to validate against a service like etherscan

Comment: its true, miners set the block timestamp - however they only have a 15-second window for their timestamp, which I believe is fine for my application. Is this `Transfer log` part of the specification? If not I wouldn't want to rely on it

Comment: It's part of the transaction receipt, assuming an event was generated from the transaction. Here's an example https://etherscan.io/tx/0x5adaf27ddbab7cafd1533d91528cecd7b2c38937b9d0d4dcdb4411f5445511ba#eventlog

Comment: Sorry what should I be looking for on that page?